# Join across databases using Subsonic 3.0

Tags: .net, sql-server, subsonic

I'm using .NET 4.0, SQL Server, looking to do an inner join across two databases on the same server. Subsonic doesn't seem to like this. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to post what you already have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a stored procedure and join tables in it

Answer (score 1):

if you have your sql-statement execute it via the CodingHorror-Class

eg.:

```
            CodingHorror cr = new CodingHorror(sqlIDetails);
            result = cr.ExecuteTypedList<QueueLog>();
```